# How do I run an .appimage on startup (19.10)?

Tags: startup, 19.10, appimage

I have recently installed [Stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer) by downloading the appimage from the github repository. I could not do it through the `ppa` method because for some reason, after adding the ppa, the machine could not find the package.

To run the appimage, I simply change the permissions to make it executable, and run the file. However, I am unable to add Stacer to my start up application on `gnome-tweaks` because it is not recognised as a application. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup) on stackoverflow.

Comment: If this is a GUI program you want to run at logon,  click "Show applications" -> search "Startup Applications".  You can just add startup programs there.  I bet there must be duplicated answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to run that using systemd services, you could use:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Your Awesome Work
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=useyouruser
LimitNOFILE=1024

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
startLimitIntervalSec=60
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/FULL/PATH/TO/YOUR/work.AppImage

PermissionsStartOnly=true
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I just got that working on 18.04 after having some hard time. Hopefully, that will be useful for 19.04

Remember to change the `User` and `ExecStart`

Answer (score 0):

try download "Stacer.deb" it essayist for installation (it build it self in the system) and then set it to startup app from it directly and auther you can add appimage app to startup app too .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ3aj.png)